# scrape next page by changing the number of page in URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have trouble scraping information on the next pages. I also have a problem when some tags change like when the website developer changes an "a href" with "h2 class" when I reach the `appart_response= requests.get(link)`

Please can you check with me the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url1 = "https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/ct/marrakech/immobilier-a-vendre-all:sc:apartments-for-sale:p:1"

appart_no = 0

while True:
    response = requests.get(url1)
    data1 = response.text
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data1,'html.parser')
    apparts = soup1.find_all('h2',{'class':'listingTit'})  
    
    for appart in apparts:
        appart_name_tag= appart.find('a')
        appart_name=appart_name_tag.text if appart_name_tag else "N/A"
        link_tag= appart.find('a')
        link=link_tag.get('href') if link_tag else "N/A"
        appart_response= requests.get(link)
        appart_data= appart_response.text
        appart_soup= BeautifulSoup(appart_data, 'html.parser')
        appart_room_tag = appart_soup.find('div',{'class':'catNav'})
        appart_room = appart_room_tag.text if appart_room_tag else "N/A"
        appart_no+=1
        print('appartment name:',appart_name,'\nappartment link:',link,'\nappartment rooms:', appart_room)
        
    url_tag1 = soup1.find('a',{'class':'arrowDot'})
    if url_tag1.get('href'):
        url1= 'https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/ct/marrakech/immobilier-a-vendre-all:sc:apartments-for-sale:p:2' + url_tag1.get('href')
        print(url1)
    else:
        break
        
print("Total apparts:", appart_no)
```

Comment: use `if/else` to run different code for different pages. If you can't find `a href` then try to find `h2 class` (instead of `else "N/A"`) or use `if/else` to skip rest of code when you get `N/A`.

Comment: if you get something different instead of `a href` then first you should display it to analyze HTML. Maybe there are some elements which you should simply skip - i.e. `ads`

Comment: I don't understand why you add `url_tag1.get('href'` to `...:p:2`. If you want next pages then you should replace `p:2` and use `p:3`, next `p:4`, etc.

Comment: some `apparts` don't have link in `H2` but it seems all of them have link in text `En savoir plus` which has `class="blueText"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is second `<a>` with text `En savoir plus`.

Sometimes it may have `href="#"` but usually when it has `#` then `<h2><a>` exists and has correct `href`. So you can try to search both links and use correct one.

I use `'div', {'class': 'contentBox'}` instead of `'h2',{'class':'listingTit'}` and then `find('a')` gives me first `<a>` (if exists) or second `<a>` and I get correct `href`.

To make sure I use `if/else` to skip `room` when I don't have `href`

---

Page has two `'a',{'class':'arrowDot'}` (left arrow, right arrow) but sometimes left arrow is hidden - but still it need to get second arrow to get correct url to next page

```
    arrow_tags = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'arrowDot'})
    
    if len(arrow_tags) > 1 and arrow_tags[-1].get('href'):
        url = arrow_tags[-1].get('href')
    else:
        break
```

---

Full working code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/ct/marrakech/immobilier-a-vendre-all:sc:apartments-for-sale:p:1"

appart_no = 0

while True:
    print('\n--- new page ---\n')
    print('url:', url, '\n')
          
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    apparts = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'contentBox'})  
    
    for appart in apparts:
        name_tag = appart.find('h2', {'class': 'listingTit'})
        name = name_tag.text.strip()
        
        link = appart.find('a').get('href', 'N\A')
        
        if link == 'N/A' or link == '#':
            print('SKIP:', name, link)
        else:
            #print('OK')
            
            appart_response = requests.get(link)
            appart_soup = BeautifulSoup(appart_response.text, 'html.parser')
            
            room_tag = appart_soup.find('div', {'class': 'catNav'})
            room = room_tag.get_text(strip=True, separator='|')  if room_tag else "N/A"
            appart_no += 1
            
            # clean up the text - split to lines, and remove extra spaces, and join it back to one string
            parts = room.split('\n')
            parts = (x.strip() for x in parts)
            room  = " ".join(parts)
            
            print('name :', name)
            print('link :', link,)
            print('rooms:', room)
        print('---')

    # there are always two `arrowDot` (left, right) but some can be hidden
    arrow_tags = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'arrowDot'})
    print(arrow_tags)
    
    if len(arrow_tags) > 1 and arrow_tags[-1].get('href'):
        url = arrow_tags[-1].get('href')
    else:
        break
        
print("Total apparts:", appart_no)
```

Result (for first page):

```
--- new page ---

url: https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/ct/marrakech/immobilier-a-vendre-all:sc:apartments-for-sale:p:1

name : Duplex de charme
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7367289/duplex-de-charme
rooms: 205 m²|5 Pièces|2 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Bon état|5-10 ans
---
name : Appartement a vendre au cœur de la palmer...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7121614/appartement-a-vendre-au-c%C5%93ur-de-la-palmeraie-de-marrakech
rooms: 205 m²|4 Pièces|3 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Nouveau|5-10 ans
---
name : Appartement de 61m² en vente Al Boughaz G...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/pa/7347251/appartement-de-61m%C2%B2-en-vente-al-boughaz-gu%C3%A9liz
rooms: 61 m²|3 Pièces|2 Chambres|1 Salle de bain|Nouveau
---
name : Appartement en vente à Ennakhil Palmeraie...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7360138/appartement-en-vente-%C3%A0-ennakhil-palmeraie-surface-totale-102-m%C2%B2-piscine-climatisation
rooms: 102 m²|3 Pièces|2 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Bon état|10-20 ans
---
name : Top affaire Appt T2 Victor Hugo grande te...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7275268/top-affaire-appt-t2-victor-hugo-grande-terrasse
rooms: 90 m²|2 Pièces|1 Chambre|1 Salle de bain|Bon état|1-5 ans|1er étage
---
name : Appartement de 82m² JNANE EL ALI
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/pa/6657050/appartement-de-82m%C2%B2-jnane-el-ali
rooms: 82 m²|3 Pièces|2 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Nouveau|2ème étage
---
name : FABULEUX. Appt T4 jardin privé res Piscin...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7013145/fabuleux-appt-t4-jardin-priv%C3%A9-res-piscine-agdal
rooms: 330 m²|4 Pièces|3 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Nouveau|1-5 ans
---
name : Appartement de 82m² JNANE EL ALI
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/pa/6657046/appartement-de-82m%C2%B2-jnane-el-ali
rooms: 82 m²|3 Pièces|2 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Nouveau
---
name : Lots de Terrains - Mysk Marrakech
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/p/3171/lots-de-terrains-mysk-marrakech
rooms: Haut standing|Finalisé|Livraison: 01/21
---
name : Appartement luxueux en vente a marrakech...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7307003/appartement-luxueux-en-vente-a-marrakech-hivernage
rooms: 135 m²|4 Pièces|2 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Bon état|5-10 ans|6ème étage
---
name : Appartement à vendre
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7361252/appartement-%C3%A0-vendre
rooms: 227 m²|5 Pièces|4 Chambres|3 Salles de bains|Nouveau|1-5 ans
---
name : Stop. Très bonne affaire
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7353960/stop-tr%C3%A8s-bonne-affaire
rooms: 47 m²|2 Pièces|1 Chambre|1 Salle de bain|Nouveau|Moins d'un an
---
name : Projet sur l'agdal avec des appartements...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7243656/projet-sur-l-agdal-avec-des-appartements-a-la-vent
rooms: 60 m²|3 Pièces|1 Chambre|2 Salles de bains|Nouveau|Moins d'un an|1er étage
---
name : Bel appartement à vendre à Guéliz avec as...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7270379/bel-appartement-%C3%A0-vendre-%C3%A0-gu%C3%A9liz-avec-ascenseur-et-terrasse
rooms: 74 m²|3 Pièces|2 Chambres|1 Salle de bain|Bon état|1-5 ans|5ème étage
---
name : Bel appartement à Marrakech avec un prix...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7279598/bel-appartement-%C3%A0-marrakech-avec-un-prix-tr%C3%A8s-raisonnable
rooms: 97 m²|4 Pièces|2 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Nouveau|Moins d'un an
---
name : Appartement en vente à Agdal. 2 chambres...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7341280/appartement-en-vente-%C3%A0-agdal-2-chambres-agr%C3%A9ables
rooms: 103 m²|3 Pièces|2 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Bon état|1-5 ans|2ème étage
---
name : A vendre rez de jardin prestigia marrakec...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7379956/a-vendre-rez-de-jardin-prestigia-marrakech
rooms: 176 m²|4 Pièces|2 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Bon état|5-10 ans
---
name : Sublime duplex dans un quartier résidenti...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7313841/sublime-duplex-dans-un-quartier-r%C3%A9sidentiel
rooms: 300 m²|5 Pièces|3 Chambres|3 Salles de bains|Bon état|5-10 ans|4ème étage
---
name : Appartement en vente à Marrakech. 1 chamb...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/6922706/appartement-en-vente-%C3%A0-marrakech-1-chambre-avec-ascenseur-et-espace-vert
rooms: 65 m²|2 Pièces|1 Chambre|1 Salle de bain|Bon état|5-10 ans
---
name : Appartement de 103m² en vente, Caprice Hi...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/pa/7152699/appartement-de-103m%C2%B2-en-vente-caprice-hivernage
rooms: 103 m²|4 Pièces|3 Chambres|2 Salles de bains
---
name : Duplex de 78m² et 43m² de mezzanine en ve...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/pa/7347254/duplex-de-78m%C2%B2-et-43m%C2%B2-de-mezzanine-en-vente-al-boughaz-gu%C3%A9liz
rooms: 121 m²|5 Pièces|4 Chambres|3 Salles de bains|Nouveau
---
name : Appartement de 90m² en vente, Big Sakane
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/pa/7095955/appartement-de-90m%C2%B2-en-vente-big-sakane
rooms: 90 m²|3 Chambres|2 Salles de bains
---
name : Appartement de 116 m² en vente, Orée de l...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/pa/6373247/appartement-de-116-m%C2%B2-en-vente-or%C3%A9e-de-la-palmeraie
rooms: 116 m²|4 Pièces|3 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Nouveau|Moins d'un an|1er étage
---
name : Appartement de 82m² JNANE EL ALI
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/pa/6649563/appartement-de-82m%C2%B2-jnane-el-ali
rooms: 82 m²|3 Pièces|2 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Nouveau|1er étage
---
name : Superbe appartement à vendre à Guéliz. 2...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7380120/superbe-appartement-%C3%A0-vendre-%C3%A0-gu%C3%A9liz-2-chambres-bien-meubl%C3%A9
rooms: 60 m²|3 Pièces|2 Chambres|1 Salle de bain|Nouveau|1-5 ans|2ème étage
---
name : Vend appartement à Bab Ighli. 2 belles ch...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7366360/vend-appartement-%C3%A0-bab-ighli-2-belles-chambres
rooms: 78 m²|3 Pièces|2 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Bon état|1-5 ans|1er étage
---
name : Joli Appart. F2 au centre Guéliz place Pa...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7081631/joli-appart-f2-au-centre-gu%C3%A9liz-place-parking
rooms: 54 m²|2 Pièces|1 Chambre|1 Salle de bain|Bon état|5-10 ans|2ème étage
---
name : Appartement F3, Résidence avec Piscine et...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/6884701/appartement-f3-r%C3%A9sidence-avec-piscine-et-jardin
rooms: 103 m²|3 Pièces|2 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Nouveau|1-5 ans|3ème étage
---
name : Duplex de 3 chambres, 2 SDB à Hay CHARAF
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7145358/duplex-de-3-chambres-2-sdb-%C3%A0-hay-charaf
rooms: 114 m²|4 Pièces|3 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Nouveau|Moins d'un an
---
name : Superbe Appartement avec Terrasse a la Ve...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7204313/superbe-appartement-avec-terrasse-a-la-vente
rooms: 100 m²|3 Pièces|2 Chambres|1 Salle de bain|Nouveau|1-5 ans|1er étage
---
name : Appart. Neuf, 2 chambres 2 SDB, parking...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7317298/appart-neuf-2-chambres-2-sdb-parking-piscine-
rooms: 65 m²|3 Pièces|2 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Nouveau|Moins d'un an|1er étage
---
name : Idéal Appartement a Gueliz
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7380001/id%C3%A9al-appartement-a-gueliz
rooms: 50 m²|2 Pièces|1 Chambre|2 Salles de bains|Nouveau|1-5 ans|1er étage
---
name : Marrakech golf City Prestigia appartement...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/7212624/marrakech-golf-city-prestigia-appartement-1-chambre-%C3%A0-vendre
rooms: 48 m²|2 Pièces|1 Chambre|1 Salle de bain|Bon état|1-5 ans|1er étage
---
name : Appartement à vendre à Agdal. 3 chambres...
link : https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/a/6827038/appartement-%C3%A0-vendre-%C3%A0-agdal-3-chambres-agr%C3%A9ables-vue-piscine
rooms: 97 m²|4 Pièces|3 Chambres|2 Salles de bains|Nouveau|Moins d'un an|1er étage
---

--- new page ---

url: https://www.mubawab.ma/fr/ct/marrakech/immobilier-a-vendre-all:sc:apartments-for-sale:p:2
```